# Newton's third law for a block on a table

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, free-body-diagram

I'm having a deep confusion regarding newton's third law for a block kept on a rigid table.

Imagine the following scenario. There is a person underwater, pushing the wall of the pool, and thus accelerating in the opposite direction. This is due to the third law. When the person applies a force on the wall, the wall pushes them back. In the FBD of the person, there is only one force acting away from the wall, which is the normal reaction from the wall. Hence the person moves in the other direction.

I'm confused, why is the same not true for a block kept on a table. The block pushes on the table, due to gravity. The Earth attracts the block, and the table comes in between. So, there is a normal force acting on the table due to the block. Due to the third law, there should be a normal force acting on the block due to the table. However, because of this normal force, why is there no upward acceleration i.e. the block flying up? Why does it remain stationary on the table. Why is it different from the swimming case. I suppose it has something to do with gravity, but I'm unable to pinpoint the exact reasoning.

Does the downward gravity cancel out this upward normal force? This means, if the experiment was carried in space, the block would fly away from the table and vice versa.

But I'm unable to understand the free body diagram here.

The block, has a downward gravity acting on the earth, and a normal force acting on the table.

So $F_{down} = mg$

However, there would be the normal force acting from the table, on the block

$F_{up} = N$

How are these two forces equal, and why is the book stationary. I can't use the FBD to say these are stationary, as the FBD already assumes they are.

So, why doesn't the normal reaction of the table make the book fly off? Why is the normal reaction from the table equal to the downward gravity i.e. weight ?

**EDIT :**

If we draw a free body diagram of the block, and set the net force on the body to be $0$, we reach the obvious conclusion, that $N=mg$. The normal force by the table is exactly opposite to the gravity, and have the same magnitude.

But, I'm trying to do the opposite. I want to first show, that these forces are equal and opposite, by some other independent means, and then conclude that the net acceleration must be $0$.

This seems to be related to the nature of the electrostatic contact force. Why does it have a value exactly equal to the gravitational pull. Moreover, for a lighter block, the force would have been lesser. This is as if, the force adjusts itself based on the mass of the block. How is this possible ? The electrostatic force adjusts its value in such a way, as to always keep net acceleration $0$. If it were stronger, the block would have an upward acceleration, and vice versa. Why is that not the case ?

Comment: About your last question: Why would you think the normal force acting from the table should be different (in magnitude) from the weight which with the book acts on the table, if that is what Newton's third law tells you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a book on a table not an example of Newton's third law?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28921/)

Comment: @Sandejo no it doesn't. It basically talks about the different action-reaction pairs. I want to know why the normal force from the table is equal in magnitude to the gravitational pull on the book.

Comment: @Koschi the normal force by the book on the table is because of gravity ( weight ), and the electromagnetic force between the surface of the book and the table. So, why is the reaction force from the table equal to the force from the earth?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can normal force and weight be similar in a body at rest?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/604077/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you draw the free-body diagram for each case then it will be all clear. I have done it for you. If there is a $\bf net\, force$ then there will be an acceleration. Notice that the vertical forces both cases cancel each other. But there exist a horizontal force for the man in the water that is not canceled hence the net force is not zero and hence he will accelerate.

> So, why doesn't the normal reaction of the table make the book fly off? Why is the normal reaction from the table equal to the downward gravity i.e. weight ?

The force from the table on the book is a reaction force in response to the force it experiences from the book which experiences a force from gravity. This force cannot be greater since the table has no ability to generate a non-reaction force. If this force is less then the book will either go through the table or bend it in some manner. If the table is sturdy then it will exactly cancel the force experienced from the book and hence the net force is zero and hence nothing will accelerate.

[image]

[image]

$\bf Edit \,due \,to\, comment:$

> Why does it have a value exactly equal to the gravitational pull

Let the force from the book on the table be $F_b$ and the force from the table to the book be $F_t$. Now from Newton's third law we have $F_t=-F_b$ where the minus sign indicates that they are in opposite direction.

> the force adjusts itself based on the mass of the block. How is this possible ?

The electromagnetic force is distance dependent. For two point charges we have $F=\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi \epsilon r^2}$ where $r$ is the distance between them. Notice that as we decrease the distance $r$ the force will be stronger, this is why it "adjusts" accordingly to how "heavy" the book is.

> If it were stronger, the block would have an upward acceleration, and vice versa. Why is that not the case ?

The reaction force from the table is contact force. Even if the force upward would be stronger (which it is not) it would stop acting as soon as the book leaves the table and hence it would immediately accelerate down due to force of gravity on the book.

Comment: Thanks, this does help a bit, but I'm still somewhat stuck. The normal force on the table, due to the block, is because of the weight of the block, and the electrostatic forces between the block on the table.  Why isn't the normal reaction force from the table, unable to overcome the gravitational force on the block, due to the earth. I've edited my question somewhat, to clarify my doubts better. Thanks !

Comment: Okay, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

> There is a person underwater, pushing the wall of the pool, and thus
> accelerating in the opposite direction. This is due to the third law.

That's incorrect. It's due to Newton's second law not third. The third law only says that the force the person exerts on the wall is equal and opposite to the force the wall exerts on the person. Whether or not the person, or the pool wall, individually accelerates depends on whether or not there is a  net force on the person and the wall, per Newton's second law to each.

> When the person applies a force on the wall, the wall pushes them
> back.

That's correct and that is due to Newton's third law.

> In the FBD of the person, there is only one force acting away from the
> wall, which is the normal reaction from the wall. Hence the person
> moves in the other direction.

In the FBD of the person there are two horizontal forces acting. The force exerted on the person by the wall which is equal and opposite to the force exerted by the person on the wall per Newton's third law, and the force of the water resistance acting in the opposite direction. The person accelerates backwards because the reaction force of the wall is greater than the water resistance force, for a net force on the person.

Meanwhile the pool wall does not accelerate because the force the person exerts on the wall is equal and opposite to the force that the structure that supports the wall exerts on the wall, for a net force of zero on the wall.

> I'm confused, why is the same not true for a block kept on a table.

Newton's laws still apply but in this case the net force on both the block and the table is zero and therefore neither accelerate.

For the block, the downward force of gravity on the block equals the upward reaction force of the table on the block for a net force of zero.

For the table, the sum of the downward force of the block on the table plus the downward force of gravity on the table itself, equals the upward reaction force of the floor for a net force of zero on the table.

I believe your confusion lies in not separately considering the effects of Newton's 3rd and 2nd laws. Newton's 3rd law only tells you that forces occur in pairs. This law does not tell you whether the objects that exert equal and opposite forces on one another will accelerate. For that you need a FBD for each individual object and examine all the forces acting on each, not just the reaction force of the other object. You then apply Newton's 2nd law $F_{net}=ma$ to each object individually.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128994/discussion-on-answer-by-bob-d-newtons-third-law-for-a-block-on-a-table).